# list & sort subfolders by number of items

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script to list & sort subfolders by number of items.

Here's what I have:

`find * | wc -l` works to return count of items.

And `for f in *; do echo "$f"; find "$f" | wc -l ; done` works, but the list is hard to parse.

So I tried to use `printf`:

```
for f in *; do 
   c=`echo find "$f" | wc -l` ; 
   printf "$c $f\n"; 
done
```

But it returns `1` for every subfolder.

And I would like to sort the final list by the number of items in each subfolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This intrigued me, so I had a go at it, here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

startIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

function echocount {
dirs=$(find -type d)
for f in $dirs; do
   c=$(find "$f" -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l) ;
   echo "$c $f";
done
}

echocount | sort -n

IFS=$startIFS
```

I find this **very** stupid and annoying in shell scripting, but I need to change the IFS so that only newlines and not spaces will signify another directory and the loop will run correctly.

BTW, in your code, the reason it always had a count of 1 is because in `echo find "$f" | wc -l`, you are actually counting the lines in `echo find "$f"`, which will always be a single line (it's just echoing literally "find whatever", not actually running the find command). If you take the `echo` out, it will do what you expect.

Also, pedants will tell you that backtick notation is deprecated. I find $() notation more readable anyway.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me: `for f in */; do c=$(find "$f" | wc -l) ; printf "$c $f\n"; done | sort` (Never heard of the `$()` thing before.) The `*/` reduces result to just directories.

Answer (score 1):

With guidance from localhost, my solution is:

```
for f in */; do 
  c=$(find "$f" | wc -l) ; 
  printf "$c $f\n"; 
done | sort -n
```